# DropWizard, OO design: Should Representation objects contain only getters and setters?

Tags: java, oop, dropwizard

Every example I've seen shows Representation objects with just getters and setters. But what if I want to implement more complex functionality for a Representation? Should I put that functionality in the Representation itself or in the service layer that receives these Representations from the database?

For example, I have a `TicTacToeRepresenation` object that contains the state of a game of Tic Tac Toe. I'd like to implement `makeMove(player, x, y)` functionality for a game. Should I add `makeMove` to `TicTacToeRepresentation` or should I add it to the service layer that receives `TicTacToeRepresentations` from the database? My understanding of OO design principles would tell me to put the functionality in `TicTacToeRepresentation` but I'm just not sure because I've never seen something like that done in practice.

Comment: A ["Representation"](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#man-core-representations) is really just a type of DTO (Data Transfer Object). Considering the question in a more general sense shows many existing .. 'debates'.

Comment: In any case, there is a strong difference between DTO+DAL/Service ("Anemic model") and DDD/Entity-as-Business designs. Neither is necessarily 'better', but which approach is (more) suitable often depends on the environment/tooling used.